# WWF - simple design decision for beginner regarding windows workflow service

Tags: workflow-foundation

I want to develop a workflow service.

What I do is the following:

1. I send the service the url to an image
2. A new record is inserted into the DB saying imageABC.jpg
   status:"pending"
3. the service downloads the image and saves it on the file system
4. when the server can begin working on the image it updates the
   status to "begin processing"
5. the service does some image processing on the image(time
   consuming)
6. the service finishes the image processing job and updates status
   to "done" in the DB table
7. the service sends a response with the url to the image

Question:
I want the computer to do the image processing on only one image at a time( I am using shared hosting so resources are limited)

How can I make sure that users can call the service, and the service will do steps 1,2,3 (because this is not extremly time consuming) but than will wait until the previous image has finished processing?

Please give me any advice. I am new and just learning.
Thank you.

PS: I also want to allow the client to see what is the status of it's image by interogating the DB for the status. Can I incorporate this into the workflow service? should I do this or should it be a separate service?

Comment: Have in mind that Workflow is a specific technology in .net and using this terminology might lead to confusion (the technology is called WWF).

Answer (score 0):

Either you do stuff synchronously or asynchronously. What you are describing sound to me like a mixture.

A single method call can do it all at once, thus forcing the client to wait until everything is done, or you can offer different methods that the client can call to determine the status, such as.

```
public enum DownloadStatus{
    Pending,
    Processing,
    Done,
}

public class YourService: IYourServiceInterface
{
     public Guid SubmitDownload(string imageUrl)...

     public DownloadStatus GetStatus(Guid downloadId) ...

     public byte[] GetResult(Guid downloadId)...

}
```

So your client would submit a download to your service. The service will then save the `imageUrl` in the database as status `Pending`. A scheduled task (another app basically) will read all pending tasks and begin downloading, marking every download task as `Processing`. When the scheduled task has downloaded and processed the image it will save the result somewhere (in a file most likely, or in the database if you insist) and set the status to `Done`... While all this is going, on the client will poll the service for the current status by calling the `GetStatus` method. The polling interval should be adjusted to the expected time it takes for your job to download and process the image. Once the client receives a `Done` status from `GetStatus` it knows that it can call `GetResult` and retrieve the image.

Comment: how can I make sure that only 1 image is processed at a time, but more images can be saved to the filesystem at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your image processing using a message queue. When file is uploaded to the server then save it to disk, insert a record into the database and queue the file for processing by inserting a message into a queue. Then process the images from the queue, one at a time, and when finished update file status in the database.